# Just who is Rhoy?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 2, there is an NPC Invader called "Rhoy the Explorer". He is most well known for his offline invasion in the Grave of Saints, but his name, and likeness do appear in other areas of the game.

For example, in NG+, in No-Mans wharf on the boat just before the Flexile Sentry, you can be invaded by a Dark spirit that resembles Rhoy (he is wearing the visible Aurous Set, but I don't recall if he has the invisible weapons). Additionally there are other links to him, like "Rhoy's resting place" in the Shrine of Amana.

I think there are some other references to him, but I can't remember properly. So just who is he?

Comment: Jubatus is right i guess. The lore about Rhoy is missing in the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if someone can answer this.

The lack of lore and indepth character creation for NPC's in dark souls 2 bothers me as well.

Most likely he was a servant of the rat king, since his invasion doesn't occur if you are the rat covenant.

Apart from that, we don't really know much else...

Comment: You can also make assumptions based off of the fact that he is using both of the Illusory Rings. Those are only available to players who have completed the game without using a bonfire at all. Although he is an NPC, he could be assumed to be very skilled.